# Razor Pages AJAX - filling the model after AJAX delete call

Tags: c#, ajax, razor-pages

I'm new to AJAX and trying to delete a row in the table without refreshing the whole page. When the button gets clicked the row is succesfully deleted from database, but i get this error:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.

Meaning the Model is empty. I don't understand how should I fill the model again after AJAX call.

Anybody dealt with this before?

My model class:

```
public class Person
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string PersonName { get; set; }
    public string PersonAddress { get; set; }
}
```

My Index.cshtml.cs:

```
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly WebApplication20.Data.ApplicationDbContext _context;

        public IndexModel(WebApplication20.Data.ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public IList<Models.Person> Person { get;set; }

        public async Task OnGetAsync()
        {
            Person = await _context.Person.ToListAsync();
        }

        public IActionResult OnPostDeleteById(int id)
        {
            var pers = _context.Person.Find(id);
            _context.Remove(pers);
            _context.SaveChanges();

            Person =  _context.Person.ToList();
            return new JsonResult
                ("Customer Deleted Successfully!");
        }
    }
```

My Index.cshtml:

```
@page
@model WebApplication20.Pages.Person.IndexModel

<p>
    <a asp-page="Create">Create New</a>
</p>

<div id="msg"></div>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Person[0].PersonName)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Person[0].PersonAddress)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model.Person)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PersonName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PersonAddress)
                </td>
                <td>
                    <form method="post">
                    <button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="DeleteId('@item.PersonId');">Delete</button>
                    </form>

                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Javascript (embed in `script` tag at bottom of page)

```
<script>
    function DeleteId(id) {
        var options = {};

        options.url = "/Person/Index?handler=DeleteById&id=" + id;
        options.beforeSend = function(xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("MY-XSRF-TOKEN",
                $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
        };
        options.dataType = "json";
        options.type = "POST";

        options.success = function (data) {
            $("#msg").html("Great Success");
        };

        options.error = function () {
            $("#msg").html("Error something went wrong");
        };
        $.ajax(options);
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Its been a while since used ajax. But if the deletion was successful we would remove the row with jquery instead of repopulating the whole page.

Comment: @RyanSchlueter - ok but the row wont get deleted from the database and thats exactly what I need

Comment: You make your ajax call to delete it from the database then if you don't get an error you remove it from ui with jquery.

Comment: @RyanSchlueter - the thing is I do get the error now. When debugging it goes like this - I press the button, post action is correctly called, row is deleted from DB, but at the last line of the code I fail to fill the Page Model resulting in '@foreach (var item in Model.Person)' to be empty and therefore resulting in the above mentioned error

Comment: oh got ya. I would look at event.preventDefault(); I think your button is triggering a page refresh.